# Normal distribution sample

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Since I'am beginner in statistics I'm stuck in simple exercise so will appreciate any help. I have mean, standard deviation and probability p(x) and need to get x. Here is the Exercise

> The patient recovery time from a particular surgical procedure is
> normally distributed with a mean of 5.3 days and a standard deviation
> of 2.1 days
>
> The 90th percentile for recovery times is?

I know that it's possible to get x from probability formula but I was wondering if there is easier way to get it.

Comment: There are tables for standard normal distributions. Just pop "standard normal distribution table" into google. Then look from the table which is closest to $\mathbb P(Z\leq \frac{t-\mu}{\sigma}) = 0.9$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik yea It solved the problem thx! Don't you want to make it answer ?

Comment: Very well, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up a table for standard normal distribution. The random variable $X$ is distributed normally. Let $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ be the standardisation. Then we're interested in
$$ \mathbb P\left (Z\leq \frac{t_0-\mu}{\sigma}\right ) = 0.9 $$
The table can be used to find the closest desirable value and one can then solve for $t_0$.

Also, verify quickly what happens when percentile increases or decreases. Or how affecting mean/st deviation changes result.

Here is a flexible [table and graph](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html) for standard normal distribution to try